# Is there a way to select an element without going back to the parent element first

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select class `this` and then get `that` without traversing first to the parent `tr` element.

This my HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>some content</div>
        <select class="this">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div>some content</div>
        <select class="that">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('.this').each(function () {
    var thisSelect = $(this),
        thatSelect = $(thisSelect).next('.that');

    console.log(thatSelect); // doesn't work
});
```

I tried to use the code above but it didn't work. I am using `each` function because there are more than one sets of these select elements on a page.

Comment: you could get all the select elements and go from there?

Comment: not quite because this and that is a set...

Comment: What is your relational context? If you are currently looking at `.this` is the `.that` you want **always** the one in the next row? Eitherway [**next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) will not go get the next set as you attempt in your code as it will only fetch the next immidiat sibling which would be a `<select>` next to it within the same level.

Comment: Yes when this is selected, I always want the immediate next "that" because it is in a set...

Comment: @Rick: there is no `immediate next "that"` in your DOM. There is nothing immediately next to the `select` with the `.this` class. However, there is a `tr` immediate next to the `tr` wrapped around `.this`. What is your reservation against `.parent()`? Going by your comment if the parent is not always a `tr` could you share the HTML alternative?

Comment: Because using parent would mean I have to keep this same dom structure for it to work.  I have other pages that are exactly like this with these two select statements but without the TR tags...

Comment: I just thought the next() function would know to find the next selector in question in the dom tree...I guess it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @Rick: `I have other pages that are exactly like this with these two select statements but without the TR tags` as you have not posted the structure of another possible structure it will be hard to create an answer which fits you perfectly and is not to hacky. Assuming the structures wrapping the `.this` and `.that` `select`s are at least similar you can use an additional class to mark the containers. I have added an example as an answer. If however the structure is completely different then you will have to post the HTML of that other structure first I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to select an element without going back to the parent
>   element first

Not with your current code. If you sometimes have a `tr` and sometimes another container as a parent the least messiest way would be to assign a class or data-attribute to the parent.

Assuming this is something you can do it would look, similar to this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
<tr class="container">
    <td>
        <div>this content</div>
        <select class="this">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="container">
    <td>
        <div>that content</div>
        <select class="that">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

That would allow your script to be agnostic to element types and you can write code safely using [**closest()**](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for example, similar to this:

```
$('.this').each(function () {
    var $thisSelect = $(this),
        $thatSelect = $thisSelect.closest('.container').next().find('.that');

    console.log($thatSelect[0]);
});
```

The above will also work on the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div>this content</div>
    <select class="this">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div>that content</div>
    <select class="that">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aESTE/) - Using a class to identify the container

---

Comment: @Rick: If the other structures are completly screwed and nothing is similar between the 2 selects then another option could be to collect the element references of all `.this` and `.that` elements in arrays and assume that `thatArray[0]` is the matching element for the element in `thisArray[0]` and `thatArray[1]` is the matching element for `thisArray[1]` and so on.

Comment: haha..thanks closest function was the one I was looking for..!! why didn't you just say that...lol...thanks again..

Comment: @Rick: I didn't know, I assumed you had a more complex requirement. Glad you got it working though :)

Comment: Was thinking to myself there has to be a function that will auto traverse to the next selector that I specify...and I thought next() was that function and it turns out it only traverses direct siblings...

Answer (score 0):

You method doesn't work because `.next()` only selects from siblings.

### jQuery

Here is a method taking advantage of the fact that `$('select')` returns them in the order they appear in the page.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UnbCs/)

```
var selects = $('select');
selects.each(function (i, select) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('this')) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < selects.length; j++) {
            if (selects.eq(j).hasClass('that')) {
                console.log(selects.eq(j));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### Vanilla JavaScript

If you're wanting to do this for performance reason then you should use vanilla JavaScript.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S76XJ/)

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    if (selects[i].className.match(/\bthis\b/)) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < selects.length; j++) {
            if (selects[j].className.match(/\bthat\b/)) {
                console.log(selects[j]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```